# Transform/replace a Class in an Actor in IBM Rhapsody model

Tags: actor, rhapsody

I need to replace a "class" with an "actor" in IBM Rational Rhapsody.
The best would be transform the class named "Pluto" in an actor named "Pluto" mantaining all the class feauteres.
Is it possible? Is there a work around to do that?

Thanks all for any suggestion.

I tried modifing "class" feautures but I didin't find the way to manage the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Rhapsody, the Actor base class is not a Class, so you can not use the menu "Change to | Class". You can only create a Class manually, and then move the containment from the Actor to the Class.